# reducing space between two lines in a title

Tags: titles

[image]

how can i reduce the vertical space between the two lines of my title? i would like the two lines to be more compact.

that's my code that i'm using to format my titles:

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\Huge\sffamily}{\thechapter}{0pt}  
  {\titlerule\vskip2pt\titlerule\vskip20pt\Huge\bfseries\filleft}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-25pt}{15pt}
```

Comment: Welcome. // Please make it a habbit to post only code which compiles when we copy and try it. This checklist/procedure may guide you to upgrade your code snippet to help you more easily: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10137/245790 . Thank you

Comment: You're likely using `setspace` or other method for “double spacing”.

Answer (score 2):

You're likely using `setspace` for “double spacing”. If not required by your institution, just don't use it.

Otherwise add `\singlespacing` to the set of instructions.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{setspace}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\Huge\sffamily\singlespacing}
  {\thechapter}
  {0pt}
  {\titlerule\vspace{2pt}\titlerule\vspace{20pt}\Huge\bfseries\filleft}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-25pt}{15pt}

\doublespacing

\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{3}

\chapter{Dimensionamento impianto fotovoltaico}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Avoid `\vskip` and use `\vspace`. The double rule is really ugly; one is enough.

I'd write in correct Italian, though: “Dimensionamento dell'impianto fotovoltaico”.